# Square matrix in c ++

Tags: c++

I did the above code to calculate the matrix of a square matrix but it does not work, can someone explain the error to me please

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int M[3][3]={{2, 4, -6}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 3, 2}};
    int n, mult;
    n=3;
    cout << "Matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << M[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            mult=M[j][i]/M[i][i];
            for (int k=i; k<n; k++){
                M[j][k]=M[j][k]-mult*M[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Echelon matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            for(int k=i; k<n; k++){
                cout << M[j][k] << "\t";
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are performing integer divisions ... Did you check what happened? Here `mult=M[j][i]/M[i][i];` the result can be equal to 0...

Comment: @Damien yes, they are divisions to perform operations between rows

Comment: The problem is not the divisions, but the fact that they are done with integers. `1/2 = 0` for example. You could try your code with `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: @Damien I understand, I already tried it and in the same way it does not work

Comment: In your post, can you please specify what problem you are facing here? If there is any error message, specify that. If the output is not what you expect, consider attaching preferred output as well as the output that you currently getting from your code. Just sharing a code and telling there is an error is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, I replaced `int` by `double`, even if that, for this particular matrix, it would work with `int`.

The main problem was that the output of the result was broken, 3 loops when two only are needed.

Note that you don't check that the Gauss pivot `M[i][i]` is not null. The code should be completed to handle this case.

Output:

Matrix:

```
2   4   -6  
1   5   3   
1   3   2
```

Echelon matrix:

```
2   4   -6  
0   3   6   
0   0   3
```

```
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;

int main() {
    double M[3][3]={{2, 4, -6}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 3, 2}};
    int n = 3;
    std::cout << "Matrix: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cout << M[i][j] << "\t";
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            double mult = M[j][i]/M[i][i];
            for (int k = i; k < n; k++){
                M[j][k] = M[j][k] - mult*M[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Echelon matrix: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
              std::cout << M[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```